# PyTorch - GPU is not used by tensors despite CUDA support is detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

As the title of the question clearly describes, even though t`orch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True`, `CPU` is used instead of `GPU` by tensors. I have set the `device` of the tensor to `GPU` through the `images.to(device)` function call after defining the `device`. When I debug my code, I am able to see that the `device` is set to `cuda:0`; but the tensor's `device` is still set to `cpu`.

Defining the device:

```
use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()  # returns True
device = torch.device('cuda:0' if use_cuda else 'cpu')
```

Determining the device of the tensors:

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images.to(device)
        labels.to(device)
        # both of images and labels' devices are set to cpu
```

The software stack:

```
Python 3.7.1
torch 1.0.1
Windows 10 64-bit
```

p.s. `PyTorch` is installed with the option of **Cuda 9.0 support**.

Comment: Whats the [CUDA compute capability](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) of the GPU?

Comment: It is a `GeForce Desktop Products - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070` on a notebook. @KlausD.

Comment: Is your network also on the device? You need to do something like `net.to(device)`, too.

Comment: Yes, it is. @dennlinger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tensor.to()` does not modify the tensor inplace. It returns a new tensor that's stored 
in the specified device.

Use the following instead.

```py
 images = images.to(device)
 labels = labels.to(device)
```